# Parsing UFW logs for IP and port numbers

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script to go through my UFW firewall logs for blocked connections, and pull out the source IP and port they were trying to connect to. I have managed to put together scripts to pull these out individually, and am having difficulty in getting the script now to output the IP and port on one line. Below is a sample of the firewall logs I have and the script. Currently it output all IPs, followed by all port numbers. What I want on each line is the source IP address and corresponding destination port from each log entry.

The ultimate aim is to see what ports each IP address is trying to connect to. My plan was to use **uniq -c**, once I can output each IP and port from the logs.

**input**

```
Nov 26 06:25:11 vps123456 kernel: [620802.845897] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:9f:c7:5d:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88 SRC=85.93.20.253 DST=10.20.30.40 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=5830 PROTO=TCP SPT=51639 DPT=735 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov 26 06:27:44 vps123456 kernel: [620955.012996] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:9f:c7:5d:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88 SRC=51.15.51.140 DST=10.20.30.40 LEN=433 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=42044 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5088 DPT=5062 LEN=413
```

**./script**

```
file="input"
for line in $file; do
    addr=$(awk '{match($0,/SRC=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print ip}' $file)
    port=$(awk '{match($0,/DPT=[0-9]{0,5}/); port = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print port}' $file)
    echo $addr, $src >> output
done
```

**output**

```
SRC=85.93.20.253 SRC=51.15.51.140, DPT=735 DPT=5062
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick `php` solution for you problem, that will print on each line the source ip address and the corresponding destination port. The script reads your input logfile line by line and process each row. Match ip address and port number into variables using regex.

```
<?php

$infile = $argv[1];

$handle = fopen($infile, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        preg_match('/.*SRC=(?<ip>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(.*DPT=)(?<port>[0-9]+).*/', $line, $m);
        if ($m) {
            print $m['ip'] . ' ' . $m['port'] . "\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    exit("Unable to open file ($finfile)");
}
```

After saving the above script into a file (ie.: get-uwf-ip-port.php), you can run in the following way:

```
php get-uwf-ip-port.php your_logfile
```

The output (source file was your two example lines):

```
85.93.20.253 735
51.15.51.140 5062
```

**UPDATE**:

And here is a native `bash` solution. The main idea here is to read the file line by line, read each line into a shell variable, extract the ip and the port number using shell parameter expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="$1"
while read line; do
  ip="${line##*SRC=}"
  ip="${ip%% *}"
  port="${line##*DPT=}"
  port="${port%% *}"
  echo $ip $port
done < "$infile"
```

I slightly modified your `awk` code, putting the ip and port matching together it will produce the same result as above:

```
awk '{match($0,/SRC=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4); match($0,/DPT=[0-9]{0,5}/); port = substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4); print ip,port}' your_logfile
```